# How to remove an part of values in R

Tags: remove-method

I have got a data frame like this:

ID A      B
1 x5.11   2,34
2 x5.57   5,36
3 x6,13   0,45

I would like to remove the 'x' of all values of the column A. How might I best accomplish this in R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very easy way:

data.frama$A <- gsub("x", "", data.frame$A)